# Recommendation for resetting data in json object using Java

Tags: java, json

I need a recommendation for this situation.

I have a json object in string format that will have pattern like this:

```
{
    "productCard" : {
        "productA" : {
            "state" : "Y",
            "desc" : "AAA",
            "someProp" : 112
        },
        "productB" : {
            "state" : "X",
            "desc" : " BBB ",
            "listSomeThing" : [
                {
                    "p1" : 1,
                    "p2" : "2"
                },
                {
                    "p2" : "3"
                }
            ]
        }
        // PRODUCT CAN ADD MORE IN FUTRE 
        // ALSO CAN HAVE OTHER OBJECT TYPE
    }
    // THIS CAN HAVE OTHER OBJECT THAT MAY BE NON RELATE INFORMATION WITH PRODUCT CARD
}
```

and then this will be parsed to an object like this:

```
class Product {
    protected String state
    protected String desc
}

class SomeThing {
    private int p1
    private String p2
}

class ProductA extend Product {
    private int someProp
}
class ProductB extend Product {
    private List<SomeThing> listSomeThing
}

class ProductCard {
    private ProductA prodctA
    private ProductB productB
}

class BaseObject {
    private ProductCard productCard
}
```

If I need to **reset some field value** in each product, and then parse to string format again, should I:

**(1)** create a new function in `Product` and then override in some child class for extra method:

```
class Product {
    void reset(){
        this.state = "X"
        this.desc = ""
    }
}

class productB extend Product {
    @override
    void reset(){
        super.reset()
        this.listSomeThing = new ArrayList<>()
    }
}
```

and in base object create new function:

```
class ProductCard {
    private ProductA productA
    private ProductB productB

    void resetAllProduct(){
        this.productA.reset()
        this.productB.reset()
    }
}

class BaseObject {
    private ProductCard productCard

    void resetAllProductCard(){
        this.productCard.resetAllProduct()
    }
}
```

then call `BaseObject.resetAllProductCard()` where business needs to reset?

**(2)** create new function in business class? Or some util class:

```
void reset(ProdctCard productCard){
    ProductA productA = productCard.getProductA();
    productA.setState("X")
    productA.setDesc("")
    ProductB productB = productCard.getProdctB();
    productB.setState("X")
    productB.setDesc("")
    productB.setListSomeThing(new ArrayList<>())
}
```

**(3)** another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Jackson Project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for that job:

```
public String reset(String json) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);

    JsonNode productCardNode = jsonNode.get("productCard");

    productCardNode.forEach(node -> ((ObjectNode) node).put("state", "X").put("desc", ""));

    ObjectNode productBNode = (ObjectNode) productCardNode.get("productB");

    productBNode.putArray("listSomeThing");

    return jsonNode.toPrettyString();
}
```

Then:

```
String jsonReseted = reset(json);

System.out.println(jsonReseted);
```

Output:

```
{
  "productCard" : {
    "productA" : {
      "state" : "X",
      "desc" : "",
      "someProp" : 112
    },
    "productB" : {
      "state" : "X",
      "desc" : "",
      "listSomeThing" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```